# Brooklyn Starting Blueprint: VMs created but Brooklyn can't SSH in

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssh, jclouds, brooklyn

I have just started using Brooklyn and I am trying to get the example from the [deploying blueprints](https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/latest/start/blueprints.html) page working fully through my AWS account.

The Maven build completed successfully and I can successfully launch the Brooklyn Web UI from `~/apache-brooklyn-0.7.0-M2-incubating/usage/dist/target/brooklyn-dist` using the steps on the [running Brooklyn](https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/latest/start/running.html) page.

When I launch the blueprint, I can see all the VMs launching in my AWS Console UI.  I can also see the key pairs and security groups created.  But the blueprint eventually fails because (I believe) Brooklyn cannot ssh into the VMs, see the first log output below.  I assume Brooklyn attempts to login to the VMs using the created key pairs somehow?

Based on the info in the [locations](https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/latest/ops/locations/index.html#clouds) page, I created a `~/.brooklyn/brooklyn.properties file` and added the following configuration:

```
brooklyn.location.jclouds.aws-ec2.identity = MyAwsAccessKeyID
brooklyn.location.jclouds.aws-ec2.credential = MyAwsSecretAccessKey
brooklyn.location.jclouds.aws-ec2.privateKeyFile = /home/username/key4brooklyn.pem
```

I created the `key4brooklyn.pem`file from the AWS Console UI and restarted Brooklyn however the blueprint still does not work, it creates the VMs but cannot access the VMs, see log output below.

```
2015-03-02 23:31:27,295 INFO  Starting MySqlNodeImpl{id=lzJhHxwD}, obtaining a new location instance in JcloudsLocation[aws-ec2:MyAwsAccessKeyID/aws-ec2] with ports [22, 3306]
2015-03-02 23:31:27,369 INFO  Starting NginxControllerImpl{id=QYRLgQPh}, obtaining a new location instance in JcloudsLocation[aws-ec2:MyAwsAccessKeyID/aws-ec2] with ports [22, 8000]
2015-03-02 23:31:27,612 INFO  Resize DynamicWebAppClusterImpl{id=iJNs2ltC} from 0 to 1
2015-03-02 23:31:28,830 INFO  Starting JBoss7ServerImpl{id=MWMGwHXx}, obtaining a new location instance in JcloudsLocation[aws-ec2:MyAwsAccessKeyID/aws-ec2] with ports [22, 9443, 10999, 8443, 8080, 9990]
2015-03-02 23:31:37,870 INFO  Creating VM aws-ec2@MySqlNodeImpl{id=lzJhHxwD} in JcloudsLocation[aws-ec2:MyAwsAccessKeyID/aws-ec2]
2015-03-02 23:31:38,508 INFO  Creating VM aws-ec2@JBoss7ServerImpl{id=MWMGwHXx} in JcloudsLocation[aws-ec2:MyAwsAccessKeyID/aws-ec2]
2015-03-02 23:31:38,983 INFO  Creating VM aws-ec2@NginxControllerImpl{id=QYRLgQPh} in JcloudsLocation[aws-ec2:MyAwsAccessKeyID/aws-ec2]
2015-03-02 23:34:55,349 INFO  Not able to load publicKeyData from inferred files, based on privateKeyFile: tried [/home/username/key4brooklyn.pem.pub] for aws-ec2@MySqlNodeImpl {id=lzJhHxwD}
2015-03-02 23:34:55,353 INFO  Not able to load publicKeyData from inferred files, based on privateKeyFile: tried [/home/username/key4brooklyn.pem.pub] for aws-ec2@JBoss7ServerImpl {id=MWMGwHXx}
2015-03-02 23:34:55,351 INFO  Not able to load publicKeyData from inferred files, based on privateKeyFile: tried [/home/username/key4brooklyn.pem.pub] for aws-ec2@NginxControllerImpl {id=QYRLgQPh}
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Oracle Java 7 installed, it is a VirtualBox VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the log output, the problem is here:

```
2015-03-02 23:34:55,349 INFO  Not able to load publicKeyData from inferred files, based on privateKeyFile: tried [/home/username/key4brooklyn.pem.pub] for aws-ec2@MySqlNodeImpl {id=lzJhHxwD}
```

The *privateKeyFile* configuration key needs to specify an `id_rsa` or `id_dsa` style key pair in two files. The corresponding `*.pub` file will be auto-detected if *publicKeyFile* is not configured. There are better instructions for [creating an ssh key](https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/latest/ops/locations/ssh-keys.html) available. It *is* confusing and better error reporting around keys (including fail-fast) is in the latest *SNAPSHOT* builds and will be included in the *M3* milestone release. Also note that the `id_rsa` file must have one and only one private key and must not contain the public key. Tedious that there are so many formats!

The `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or other configured key-pair is just used by Brooklyn for setting up ssh access to the VM after it is provisioned. By default, jclouds (which we use under the covers) will create a temporary AWS key-pair to get initial access to the VM. We'll then automatically add the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the VM's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (creating a user on the VM that by default has the same name as the user who is running the Brooklyn process).

The `key4brooklyn.pem` file you downloaded is the private part of the AWS key-pair. By default, this will *not* be used because jclouds will create its own key-pair.

If you wanted jclouds to use your pre-existing key pair then you'd have to use the following configuration setting:

```
brooklyn.location.jclouds.aws-ec2.keyPair = MyKeypairName
```

Where *MyKeypairName* is the name of the key-pair according to AWS.

Comment: Also note that versions of Brooklyn more recent than `0.7.0-M2-incubating` (which is just `SNAPSHOT` at the moment) have a bit more smarts and will infer the public key in this situation, resolving your problem.